# CellEditor value rollback in objectlistview

Tags: c#, objectlistview

I use objectlistview (2.9.1), I want to rollback the value of CellEditor.Text when the input is not qualified, and display on UI immediately.
Code:

```
private void olv_CellEditFinishing(object sender, CellEditEventArgs e)
{
  int iQuantity = 0;
  int iPreviousQuantity = order.Quantity.HasValue ? order.Quantity.Value : 0;
  string sCellText = ((ObjectListView)sender).CellEditor.Text;
  if (Int32.TryParse(sCellText, out iQuantity) && iQuantity >100)
    {
         // pop up a message box 

        //Here I　want to rollback the previouse quantity
        ((ObjectListView) sender).CellEditor.Text = iPreviousQuantity.ToString();   

        //display the previous quantity immedidatly
       this.olv.RefreshItem(e.ListViewItem);
    }
}
```

but this does not work.

Comment: What about setting `e.Cancel = true;`? This will cancel the CellEdit and keep the old value.

Comment: "but this does not work" and "It did not work" is not enough information to help you any further.

Comment: OK, thanks. I will investigate further and let you know if any update. It seems that e.cancel =true works,as I saw the value rollback for a few seconds, and turn to the new value again. I check the code, have not find any code to do that (turn to the new value).

Comment: @MacLee if you need to **validate** input value then you should not use CellEditFinishing event but CellEditValidating event.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you register the event :

```
    this.DBTLviewAfter.CellEditFinishing += new BrightIdeasSoftware.CellEditEventHandler(this.DBTLviewAfter_CellEditFinishing);
```

and here is my event function:

```
    private void DBTLviewAfter_CellEditFinishing(object sender, CellEditEventArgs e)
    {
        string toBeEditingStr = (string)e.NewValue;
        if(toBeEditingStr == "")
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

If the value after edited is empty, the cell won't be changed.